# Question in ZF set theory 1

Tags: set-theory

For the following predicate $\phi(x)$, show why the set $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ does or does not exist:

$$\exists y(y\in x).$$

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think your comment may be confusing because it doesn't type-check: you say "the set" and then a predicate.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

First, we can dissect what this is saying in English. For $\phi(x) = \exists y \, (y \in x)$, $\phi(x)$ is saying "There exists an element of $x$", or in other words, "$x$ is not empty."

Since this predicate describes all sets except $\varnothing$, we expect that just like the set of all sets, this $\{x \mid \phi(x)\}$ will be too big to exist. (It includes all sets but one.)

How do we prove it? Well, suppose towards contradiction that $A = \{x \mid \phi(x)\}$ exists. Now take the union with $\{\varnothing\}$, and you get...what set? You should already know that the resulting set cannot exist, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Walter Please click the "ask question" button at the top of the page to ask a new question.

Comment: I think it's much easier to ask similar questions here. I wanted to ask $\exists y (y \notin x)$ So there is an element not in $x$.

Comment: @Walter Okay. That would also be the set of all sets, because for any set there is some thing not in that set. So that means $\{x | \phi(x)\}$ doesn't exist for that $\phi$. If that doesn't help, please do ask a new question, it will allow anyone to assist you and not just me (who may not have a chance to respond). It will be good to link back to this question if you ask a new one.